# C# Ghost Outline Form Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

Normally, my C# app shows the full window contents dynamically resizing while the form itself is resizing.

I clearly remember some apps doing this very nice effect where rather than doing this, it would just show a ghostly border during resize and THEN redraw the window.

How do I get this lovely effect in my forms? I can't find any thing on Google that appears to pertain to this.

Comment: Wasn't that on old windows platforms?

Comment: Yeah, that's a Windows feature of an older version of Windows I think.  You'd have to do a lot of custom graphics work to get that behavior, I think.

Comment: Agreed...that's an OS setting (but still available in Win 7/8).  Turn off the [Show Window Contents While Dragging](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/75059-show-window-contents-outline-while-dragging.html) option.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Just wondering - does this imply that you can only make it happen for all programs, or is there some way to make it only happen for your own program?

Comment: I don't think you can do it for just your program.  Maybe you could trap when your Form starts resizing, toggle that setting, then toggle it back afterwards.  See [ResizeBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ResizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend(v=vs.110).aspx).  Haven't tested it out, no idea if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

PInvoke `SystemParametersInfo` to change it, but it changes for all windows.

Here is a references for all commands: [MSDN SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#UIeffect)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, int lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    int SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS = 0x0025;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS,0,0,2);
    Application.Run(new Form());
}
```

Comment: How do you turn it back?

Comment: `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS,1,0,2);`